# Hazard rate of a normal distribution

Tags: pr.probability

Is the hazard rate of a normal distribution a convex function?

It appears to be the case numerically. Does anyone have a formal proof?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: It is an concave function. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1394582/261589.

Comment: Yes, convex. This question is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349555/standard-normal-distribution-hazard-rate